# Calculating churn in R data frame: Data calculation in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have a data frame with first column with customer names/id and M0:M100 columns denoting Revenue received from the month of joining. Small sample below:

I need to calculate revenue churn Month wise (M0 to M100) for the data frame:

A customer churns in a month say M3 when he has a non zero value in M2 and sum of all future months is 0. For example M2!=0 & Sum (M3:Mn)==0. In this case the churned value in M3 is the revenue we got in M2 from customer.

```
customer<-c("Robin","Tim","John","Casey","Jack")
M0<-c(234,21,22,22,32)
M1<-c(33,33,232,221,322)
M2<-c(3,2,25,98,100)
M3<-c(0,2,0,98,0)
M4<-c(3,0,0,0,0)
df=data.frame(customer,M0,M1,M2,M3,M4)

Output:
       M0 M1 M2 M3 M4
Churn  0  0  0 125 100
```

Month M3: Jack & John churn with (100 & 25 value respectively)
Month M4: Tim & Casey Churn with (2 & 98 value respectively)

And Robin is still active. Need to this for a large set of data and struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the information from last active month:

```
library(reshape)
library(dplyr)
df %>% melt(id="customer") %>% group_by(customer) %>% 
mutate(month=as.numeric(substr(variable, 2,5)), maxmonth=max(month[value!=0])) %>% 
filter(month==maxmonth)
```

Result:

```
  customer variable value month maxmonth
    (fctr)   (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)    (dbl)
1     John       M2    25     2        2
2     Jack       M2   100     2        2
3      Tim       M3     2     3        3
4    Casey       M3    98     3        3
5    Robin       M4     3     4        4
```

Of course, you can just select value from there.

EDIT:

If you'd like to see the sum of churn values per month, this will do (df2 being the result of previous step):

```
df2 %>% mutate(month=month+1) %>% group_by(month) %>% summarise(sum=sum(value))
```

Result:

```
  month   sum
  (dbl) (dbl)
1     3   125
2     4   100
3     5     3
```

of course the last line denotes the last month's values of active customers, thus can be skipped.

Comment: Could you explain how can I select... For example, how do I find value of churning in M3?

Comment: would you like to generate a sum of churning values per month? if so, just add %>% group_by(variable) %>% summarise(sum=sum(value)) - edited the answer.